# Fancybox + onsubmit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, onsubmit

Anyone know how to fire Fancybox with an iframe onsubmit form? 
Regards!

Comment: I think we need more information to answer your question. Can you share some sample code of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many resources available on basis of Google Search :

- [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)
- [How to Use](http://fancybox.net/howto)
- [jQuery FancyBox Plugin](http://www.jdmweb.com/resources/FancyBox)

I don't know this will solve your issue or not. Please Correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you.