# Fancybox - Ajax Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, fancybox

I have a custom image gallery which populates a div with thumbnails, each contained in a fancybox group.

When you click one (it opens in fancybox) and you can press Prev/Next to cycle between images on the first "page".  To move between pages, you have to close fancybox and change pages then open a new thumbnail.  This new set of photos is retrieved via ajax.

To show you exactly what I'm talking about, 
http://www.speedcountry.com/mSpeed323/Mazda_MAZDASPEED3

How can I use fancybox to switch pages and load the next set of images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear there are any internal methods in FancyBox, so you'll have to modify the plugin. I took the liberty of making a minor change and posting a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/UagVd/1/) - in the demo, open any image in a FancyBox popup, then press Enter on the keyboard. It will load all of the images into the gallery and start from the first.

Modified line 887, then insert a line before 892:

```
$.fancybox.pos = function(pos, array) { // array parameter added
    if (busy) {
        return;
    }

    if (array) { currentArray = array; } // new line
```

So, basically add "array" as a function parameter, then add the `if (array)...` line.

To use it, just call the `pos` function while FancyBox is open. This is the code from the demo:

```
// pos( index of image, jQuery object of gallery objects )
$.fancybox.pos(0, $('#examples a[id]'));
```

*Note: Initially I just used `$('a[id]')` and it included the image that was inside fancy box.

---

**Update**: So like you said, you are loading in more images using ajax... I'm guessing you are just getting a list of image urls. Starting with a url, you will need to form and add these images to the page in a hidden area:

```
<div id="ajax-loaded" style="display:none">
 <a href="#" title="image1 title"><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
 <a href="#" title="image2 title"><img src="image2.jpg"></a>
 ...
 <a href="#" title="imageN title"><img src="imageN.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Then you can make an array of jquery objects `$('#ajax-content img')` to the `$.fancybox.pos` function as a second paramter, and start with the first image (the zero)

```
// ajax complete, add images to gallery
$.fancybox.pos( 0, $('#ajax-loaded a') );
```

**Update #2**: I wrapped the above HTML in links and the jQuery selector after I found that it is necessary if you want to include an image caption.

Comment: I see your logic here but I'm a bit confused on the second bit (and the demo doesn't work for me).  What am I passing in the array argument?  Can you elaborate on "jQuery object of gallery objects"

Comment: Hiya, the demo stopped working because I was linking to the fancybox files on their website. I just switched all the links and added the css, so it should work now. The second bit with `$.fancybox.pos` is an internal fancybox function that is sort of like a "goto" image #... All I did was replace the current array (jQuery object array) with one that you add yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, bounty awarded

Comment: @Mottie Unfortunately, it did not worked for me. Could you please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351626/jquery-fancybox-with-ajax/31352383)  question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted some useful links of FancyBox in my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878602/fancybox-onsubmit-button/5003027#5003027). Please check them.

If you don't find it useful, please correct me.

Meanwhile, if there is any issue with the implementation, please post code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just added `$("#profileGallery .vehiclePictures:first").click()` at the end of `prepGallery()`. So after your AJAX call, it will automatically "click" the photo.

Comment: That would be an event for the first photo in the gallery if it were explicitly clicked.  How can I modify it so that if they click picture "n" and move to the last one on the page (with fancybox arrows)... it makes an ajax call?

Comment: @pws5068 You can use onStart event to check if the current image is the last, so you can do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/854863).